# How to set 2 shipping options

Tags: magento2, module, custom-options, delivery

I require 2 options for shipping to be set in magento 2.18.

First option is Home delivery @ £1
Second Option is using a delivery company by weight

is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes! Please read the following links from Magento2 docs for setting up your shipping methods:

- First option: [Flat rate](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-flat-rate.html)
- Second option: [Dimensional weight](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/weight-dimensional.html)

Comment: And they can be used simultaneously? customer can select which one?

Comment: Yes, you can have several shipping methods at the same time and the customers can choose the one that they prefer.